# Cannot have USE statement in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to create a stored procedure that I can use later on in an insert statement. Here is the following query I am trying to have inside the procedure:

```
USE live12
SELECT 
    ca.value('(/CA/@ID)[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)'),
    ca.value('(/CA/@value)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'),
    ca.value('(/CA/@Date)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')
FROM log
```

I have read that I cannot use the "USE" statement in the stored procedure, however when I take that out the SELECT code gets underlined in red because it doesn't know that the column ca exists, and that log is a table. How can I fix this?

Comment: When you take out the select code it makes no sense. That is why it is red - the parser just tries to find the first more specific error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you write it this way?

```
SELECT 
    ca.value('(/CA/@ID)[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)'),
    ca.value('(/CA/@value)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'),
    ca.value('(/CA/@Date)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')
FROM live12.dbo.log
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the stored procedure in `live12` database.

Answer (score 0):

Use [alias](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-clause-transact-sql):

```
SELECT 
    x.ca.value('(/CA/@ID)[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)'),
    x.ca.value('(/CA/@value)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'),
    x.ca.value('(/CA/@Date)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')
FROM live12.dbo.log x
-- OR:
-- FROM live12.dbo.log AS x
```